# Create a list of mode values based on table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a table that will show me the mode of a data set. The data is contained in 3 columns.

Sample Data

[image: Sample Data]

Though the actual data set is thousands of rows

I am trying to identify what the most frequent rate paid is for each weight and zone.

I can get an average via a pivot table. I can also have a pivot table show me how many times each rate shows up in each weight and zone, but that is just a count. I would like it to show me the mode rate.

Any ideas on how to work this would be very appreciated!

Update: This is what I need the end result to look like:

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: why not create a pivot table with a count of paid rates per weight and zone, and then sort descending by count?  That will put the most frequent on top

Comment: That still wouldn't solve the problem entirely. And each column would have to be manually sorted that way. At least according to what I am able to do with a pivot table. I will update the question with what I need the end result to look like.

Comment: [Excel has a `MODE` function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-mode-function)

Comment: Yes, Yes it does. And how can I use that mode function to give the output I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to what I needed to do here: https://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/02/11/match-two-criteria-and-return-multiple-rows-in-excel/

I was able to use this formula to create a list of values. From that list I used a mode and min formula to return the mode or min value.

From that I was able to populate a table with the values as needed.

[Screen shot of the results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So7Z7.png)